# rails revert a activerecord update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have a use case where a user can submit an order. This order contains some information of how many items in my inventory. However, a user can also cancel this order after the order is created. In that case, the inventory should be added back.

I'm wondering how shall I implement this in rails? I'm not sure the correct google key words to search for it

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to implement the logic explicitly. So have an action that deletes the Order and also sets the inventory back to what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its ok to go straight way to code

inventory has_many items
order has_many items

items belong_to order
items belong_to inventory

when order created deducts items_amount in inventory
when order cancel(remove, destroy) add items_amount in inventory

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @user2280271's answer I'd build a service object to take care of the logic, and then just call it from the controller, here's a great post on service objects: http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/04/30/gourmet-service-objects.html

So maybe you'll end up with something like this:

```
class OrdersController
  def cancel
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    if CancelOrder.call(@order)
      redirect_to order_path(@order), notice: 'Your order has been canceled'
    else
      redirect_to order_path(@order), alert: "There's been an error while canceling your order"
    end
  end
end
```